# All possible factor pairs including negatives (python)

Tags: python, factors

So I wanted to figure out if there is a way to display all factor pairs of a number *including negatives.* For example, factor pairs of 6 would be (1, 6) and (2, 3). But it would also be (-1, -6) and (-2, -3). I have the basic code for all positive factors, but could anyone help with figuring out negatives too?

```
num1 = int(input("Enter number here: "))
def factorPair(num1):
    return [(i, num1 / i) for i in range(1, int(num1**0.5)+1) if num1 % i == 0]
print(factorPair(num1))
```

Comment: Once you have the +ve factor, isn't it trival to work out the -ve one? e.g. if +ve is `(x,y)` -ve is `(-x,-y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve you goal like this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter number here: "))
def factorPair(num1):
    a = [(i, num1 / i) for i in range(1, int(num1**0.5)+1) if num1 % i == 0]
    b = [(-i*, -(num1 / i)) for i in range(1, int(num1**0.5)+1) if num1 % i == 0]
    return a + b
 print(factorPair(num1))
```